# Similarity metric for one-dimensional time-series data-sets

Tags: time-series, dataset, similarities

I have a setup consisting of measured (one-dimensional) sensor data from n subjects. For each subject, measurements were performed from different angles. The amounts of angles and acquired measurements are inconsistent, even though the amounts of samples for each measurement are always equal.

Please see below for a summarizing visualization:

```
Subject 1:
[ # all measurements from subject 1
    [ # o measurements from angle 1 of subject 1 
        [x_{11},x_{12},...x{1w}], # measurement 1 from angle 1 of subject 1 containing w samples
        [x_{11},x_{12},...x{1w}], # measurement 2 from angle 1 of subject 1 containing w samples
        ...
        [x_{11},x_{12},...x{1w}], # measurement o from angle 1 of subject 1 containing w samples
    ],
    ...
    [ # p measurements from angle k of subject 1
        [x_{11},x_{12},...x{1w}], # measurement 1 from angle z of subject 1 containing w samples
        [x_{11},x_{12},...x{1w}], # measurement 2 from angle z of subject 1 containing w samples
        ...
        [x_{11},x_{12},...x{1w}], # measurement p from angle z of subject 1 containing w samples
    ]
],
...
Subject n:
[ # all measurements from subject 1
    [ # q measurements from angle 1 of subject n
        [x_{11},x_{12},...x{1w}], # measurement 1 from angle 1 of subject 1 containing w samples
        [x_{11},x_{12},...x{1w}], # measurement 2 from angle 1 of subject 1 containing w samples
        ...
        [x_{11},x_{12},...x{1w}], # measurement q from angle 1 of subject 1 containing w samples
    ],
    ...
    [ # r measurements from angle z of subject n
        [x_{11},x_{12},...x{1w}], # measurement 1 from angle z of subject 1 containing w samples
        [x_{11},x_{12},...x{1w}], # measurement 2 from angle z of subject 1 containing w samples
        ...
        [x_{11},x_{12},...x{1w}], # measurement r from angle z of subject 1 containing w samples
    ]
]
```

I'm looking for a statistical metric providing information how similar the data-sets (i.e. all measurements from all angles from all subjects) and sub data-sets (i.e. all measurements from all angles from a single subject) are to each other. I'm aware of methods like [Dynamic Time Warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) or [Cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) but these metric only provide information about the similarity of two measurements and not about the similarity of data-sets consisting of several measurements.

Recently I learned about [Canonical Correlation Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_correlation) but this method does not seem to be suited for data-sets containing inconsistent amounts of measurements.

Additionally, I'm also looking for Python solutions implementing the sought-for metric but I realize that this would be better suited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: lookup [coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_(signal_processing)) and cross correlation, this will also include phases, cross spectral density analysis

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, these methods (or at least the corresponding Python implementations [https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.coherence.html and https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html] I found) seem to only compare two time-series with each other. However, I'm looking for a solution comparing complete data-sets containing several time-series with each other.

Comment: maybe get PCA of your dataset's time series, then compare PC1 between data sets

Comment: I ended up doing what you proposed: Getting the first PC of each data set and then comparing those PCs with DTW, which results in a single scalar for each comparison. I wonder whether this is a statistically sound approach. Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: it's a sound approach, of course, especially if it works for you. you could as well go with as simple of an approach as a simple average, instead of PC1. it may have worked almost as well